# Periodic password change needed when using 2-step verification?

Tags: authentication, passwords, password-cracking, multi-factor

I know that it's considered good online security hygiene to change one's login passwords every 6 months or so.  Is that needed on sites with 2-step verification?  Isn't the 2nd step what will keep my account secure regardless if someone has the password or not?  Indeed, are passwords needed at all in a world of 2-step verification?

Comment: What happens if there is a flaw in the 2FA subsystem?

Comment: @schroeder [Case in point...](http://www.securityweek.com/two-factor-authentication-bypassed-simple-attacks)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Indeed, two factor authentication (2FA) will prevent anyone from accessing an account without having both authentication factors.

That being said, the typical implementation of 2FA online is a password paired with a short code, either on a keyfob or sent via SMS.  The [standard RSA SecurID keyfobs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA_SecurID) that have been around for a couple decades now and [Google's 2 step verification program](https://www.google.com/landing/2step/features.html), as a couple examples, both use 6 digit numeric codes as the second factor.  With only 1 million possibilities, that's a fraction of a second to brute-force on even obsolete computing devices.  Granted, there are other security measures in place (like account lockouts and time restrictions) that offer protection against brute force attacks on the second authentication factor, but it's such a small number of possibilities that it's probably feasible to overcome with just a little effort and ingenuity.  For example, renting a botnet (which can be done for literally several dollars) and using a modified ["low and slow" brute force attack](http://www.immutablesecurity.com/index.php/2009/10/06/low-and-slow-ssh-brute-force-attacks/) against the second factor, if the password is known.  As pointed out in the comments, if we assume 3 guesses at one in a million odds per "attack", before the code resets, we get a ~3 in one million chance of succeeding per attack. Assuming we were able to launch one of these treble attacks against the second factor every 30 seconds, we could get a 26% chance of succeeding do in a couple weeks or so (100,000 attacks, 1- 0.999997<sup>100000</sup>), and better than 50% chance of success in approximately a month (250,000 attacks, 1- 0.999997<sup>250000</sup>).

And bear in mind that brute-force attacks are not the only possible attack against the second factor or the best, or most likely... they're probably about the worst way to attack this second factor, and they're likely to be at least somewhat feasible.  It's not *that* difficult to con a cellular service provider into giving over control of an account/phone number (to receive the 2FA SMS message themselves), or steal a keyfob, or [exploit vulnerabilities in the 2FA system itself](http://www.securityweek.com/two-factor-authentication-bypassed-simple-attacks), and so on.

At a high level, 2FA is about verifying someone as an authorized user in two different ways.  "Something you know, **and** something you have."  People are bad at generating unguessable secrets (something you know), as well as being bad at keeping them secret, and people are also not great at keeping control over physical things (something you have)... but they're much more likely to be able to do one or the other at any given time. As long as I can do one or the other, 2FA will keep my account [relatively] secure.  On its own, that 2nd factor is little more than a very, very weak password, (at least as implemented by most websites/webservices) and people protecting their accounts with very, very weak passwords is one of the reasons that 2FA exists in the consumer space today.

So yes, passwords are still needed with most 2FA, and occasional password changing is still a wise precaution. The relative weakness of the second factor in typical implementations means that it's not secure enough to stand on its own, without the secrecy of a good password for the first authentication factor.  And because a good password as a first factor is still required, that does mean following good password practices (strong password, not re-using it, changing it occasionally).

Comment: However, the thing with 2FA is that the codes are expiring. So even rate limiting logins so 3 incorrect 2FA logins = 30 second lockout, will make the attacks difficulty like guessing one 6 digit PIN with 3 tries, as the PIN is changed each 30 second. So using a low-and-slow brute force attack on a time-based 2FA isn't possible.

Comment: @sebastiannielsen Each attack instance would have ~3 in 1,000,000 odds of success, which is pretty lousy.  Enough instances, though, and your odds of succeeding at least once (even on those same lousy odds) get pretty good, and one is all you'd need.  I suppose I could have explained that better. (For example, 10,000 attempts at those odds give an almost 3% chance of succeeding a least once, and 10,000 is a pretty small number to a computer, let alone a botnet.)

Comment: Of course, the lockout should be done on account, not client computer. So each attack would take 30 seconds to perform. Lets say that the attack gurenteed succeeds after having tried 500 000 codes. Each 3 codes takes 30 seconds, and 1 code take then 10 second. Would still be 2 months of constant attacking. But still 500 000 codes aren't gureanteeing any attack as the target (correct code) is moving all the time, as opposed to a password, where attack succeds at roughtly 50%.

Comment: And somewhere here, the attack will get noticed. And a account could be configured so lets say after 30 incorrect codes, you must provide 2 subsuquent codes to "reset" the lockout. Then the code effectively becomes 12 digit. Good luck cracking that....

Comment: @sebastiannielsen The question seems to be about general sites online, (`good online security hygiene` ... `Is that needed on sites with 2-step verification`) and typical users, neither of which tend not to be very security conscious. I think it's a fair assumption that these more advanced or involved security measures aren't going to come into play, nor are the hardware-based keys or smart cards you suggested in your answer.  And, yes, my answer acknowledged that brute forcing isn't the only option for attacking a 2nd auth factor, but shows how weak this 2nd factor is in most implementations.

Comment: Very grateful for both of your insights, HopelessN00b and @sebastiannielsen.  So, I guess I'll continue changing my passwords which is super tedious.  I've got around 400 stored in 1Password and only gotten through the A's so far.  Maybe there's an automated way to update one's passwords.  Also, I've been using sms and Google's Authenticator app for 2SA.  Should I be using the Yubikey Sebastian Nielsen mentions instead, whatever that is?

Comment: @BenU I would suggest that every 6 months is a fairly aggressive timetable for password aging, especially if you use 2FA and good password practices. I, personally, do it on an annual basis (well, I procrastinate, so it's probably more like 15 months or so) and would say that in the context of online services, the biggest reason for password changing is so that your credentials don't get discovered as the result of one of the big password breaches we hear about, where hackers brute force password hashes - and that's a small risk if you have strong passwords you don't reuse.

Comment: @BenU The Yubikey is a extremely secure token as it has a uncopiable secure element with a device key that cannot be extracted. If you use it, I would suggest using it with U2F. Then you no longer need to change password for those sites that use U2F.

Comment: @BenU [Yubikeys](https://www.yubico.com/products/yubikey-hardware/) come in a few varieties, and are great products, but probably won't be supported as a 2nd authentication factor with a lot of the services you use.  They're worth checking into anyway, because they can probably be used with a lot of them, and I'd agree that with a Yubikey as your 2nd auth factor, changing your password is not very likely to help account security in any significant fashion.

Comment: @BenU, does 1Password have the ability to set an "expiration date" to remind you when to change each password? What I've done in KeePass is set dates spread out over a year on all my accounts, so every month or so I need to change a small handful of passwords, rather than trying to change all of them in one weekend or something.

Answer (score 1):

No. I would say, that the 2FA device in question, will protect your account more than the password. The idea behind the 2FA device, is to prevent someone remote to you, to access your account. Eg, hacking it from the other side of the globe. (NOTE: Does NOT apply to certain event based tokens with 6/8 digits - see later)

However, changing password is a measure to prevent from stolen and/or guessed password, for example leaked password database without knowledge. Or if someone shoulder-surfed you. Or if password leaked due to a trojan or virus on some third party computer you used.

When you use a 2FA token, if the token is completely software based, there is a possibility that a adversiary with physical access to your software token, has copied it. In such cases, changing the password can effectively lock out a attacker with a stolen "Token Seed", from using your account.

If you however, use a secure token technology that can't be copied, for example a physical token, YubiKey, smart-card based token, or even a smartphone-based token that uses [hardware-based seed storage](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/keystore.html), then you are safe, and then you don't need to change password. You could even use a easy password like "Password1".

The chance that someone physically steals the token, is minimal, and if that would happen, you would be able to detect this easily ("Where is my token?"), and then perform actions to reset and block the stolen token.

Depending on token technology, there is a risk that the token code can be brute forced. Time-based tokens do not have this limitation, as you can always enforce a time limit of 30 second after 3 failed logins, and it will be impossible to brute force the token, as it changes each 30 second. Same applies for challenge-based token, you just generate a new challenge for each try, so each try will have a different "correct token code", so the attacker must effectively guess the token code on first try.

A "event based token" however, do have the risk that someone brute forces it, unless the token code have enough characters to not be effectively brute-forced (for example, Yubikey is a secure event-based token that cannot be brute-forced)
But 6-digit event-based tokens aren't secure.